# Breeze error only when loading data via button click

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I am using Breeze to load data in to my application.  I do an initial load of the data when the app loads and that works fine.  I also have a button that when clicked is supposed to get the data again.  However when I click that button, the query fails, but the error message IS the json data.

Here's the code for the function:

```
var getULSLogs = function (filters) {

    var query = entityQuery
        .from('ULSLogs')
        .orderByDesc('LogTime')
        .take(app.rowLimit);

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(function(e) {
            alert(e);
        });

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        console.log('Query Succeeded');
        data.results.forEach(function (item) {
            vm.ulslog.logs.push(item);
        });
    }
};
```

Since I don't get an actual error message, I'm not sure where to go from here.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I faced the same error when trying to refresh an entity with the relations {User} <-> {UserRoleMap} <-> {Role}. I traced the error down to `proto.attachEntity` of `EntityGroup`. The following code is present:
    if (this._entities[ix] === entity) {
       aspect.entityState = entityState;
       return entity;
    }
    throw new Error("This key is already attached: " + aspect.getKey());
If the entity is being refreshed from a server query, I'd think the equality comparison would fail and cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

The return value in the 'fail' promise is a javascript object with a number of properties. Depending on the failure you may find more information by looking at this object in detail in a debugger.

Comment: Thank you, I just wrote out the error to the console, and it pointed me to the error: 'This key is already attached'.  Now I just need to figure out how to get rid of that entity and replace it with the new one.

Comment: Not sure you need to.  Breeze automatically merges incoming entities with any entity in the cache with the same key.  Any navigation properties are also updated. So try removing your 'forEach' loop in 'querySucceeded', you may find that your collection is already updated.

Comment: I suspect Jay is correct. If so, the exception is thrown in your querySucceeded method, not by Breeze. Exceptions from either source would flow into your queryFailed. A breakpoint at the top of querySucceeded would resolve that question.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.  I get that error no matter what I do if the entities are there.  However, if I clear out all of the entities in the manager, then re-run the query it works fine with no issues. @Ward that being said, it's not getting to the querySucceeded method.  It always goes to queryFailed.

Comment: Forgive me when I say "this sounds impossible". Of course we do 6 impossible things before breakfast so who knows. Check the query response body in the HTTP reply; does it have an exception in it or does it have JSON data. If there is JSON data and it never gets to the querySucceeded method, then there is a failure during the merge into cache. **Is it possible that the entities from the server have duplicate key values?**. Check the payload. The fact that it works when the manager is empty and fails when the manager has entities is curious.